# MS Graph API file download from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to download XML files from a form library with the Graph API but it is not working. I am referencing the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which I think is telling me the correct syntax is `GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content`. However when I use that syntax using Graph Explorer it gives me 404 File Not Found. Next I tried the syntax `GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content` and that returns a status code 0 but the message body just says {"isTrusted": true}. I should note if I remove the last parm on the URL and use the syntax of `GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}` it does bring back information on the file.

Is there something wrong with the syntax? Is this perhaps not something you can do with XML files in a form library? Is this maybe a limit of Graph Explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you hit `/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content` endpoint, Microsoft Graph responds with 302 redirect which the browser rejects due to CORS policy.

Here is an explanation from [Downloading OneDrive files in JavaScript apps section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/working-with-cors?view=odsp-graph-online#downloading-onedrive-files-in-javascript-apps):

> To download files from OneDrive in a JavaScript app you cannot use the
>   /content API, since this responds with a 302 redirect. A 302 redirect
>   is explicitly prohibited when a CORS preflight is required, such as
>   when providing the Authorization header.
>
> Instead, your app needs to select the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
>   property, which returns the same URL that /content would have
>   redirected to. This URL can then be requested directly using
>   XMLHttpRequest. Because these URLs are pre-authenticated they can be
>   retrieved without a CORS preflight request.

To download a file in Graph Explorer, first make a request that includes the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` property:

```
GET /drive/items/{item-id}?select=@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
```

and then file could be downloaded by marking another request for the Url provided in `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` property

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent my whole day trying to figure out why /content does not work.